# Check status of the long running query

Tags: mysql, database, jdbctemplate

I have a database query which deletes from database with some given conditions. The query is being initiated by an endpoint which timeouts if the query takes a long time (which it does). The service which calls this endpoint needs to do some other tasks after this operation is successful. So we need to know when this query completes. The query is :

> DELETE FROM foo WHERE creation_time BETWEEN ? AND ? AND bar_id = ?

How do I know when the query completes? I am using **jdbctemplate** for querying the database.
I thought of one option but now sure how the `between` query works internally.

I thought of creating a status endpoint which checks if the query is still running? The endpoint will check if there is any row in `foo` where `creation_time = FROM` and `bar_id = id`.
But I don't know how mysql handles the `BETWEEN` query internally. If it starts deleting from the **FROM** or the **TO** or anything in between.

Short question : How do I check if my query is still running or finished with jdbctemplate?

Comment: Can you fix the timeout issue? That seems like the root of the problem here.

Comment: Fixing the timeout isn't reliable. We need a solid proof that the call is fully executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can execute the `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` command. See the [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-processlist.html) for a good description of the command.

This will show all running threads, along with the query that is currently executing and the time that it has been running.

Then parse the output to see if your query is still running.

Hope this helps.